# How to get the first sheet of an excel workbook using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx, python-3.9

I'm able to get the desired sheet by using wb["sheet_name"] method but I want to get the first, or let's say the nth sheet, regardless of the name.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = xlsx_dir)   # xlsx_dir is the workbook path

ws = wb["Details"]   # Details is the sheet name
```

Comment: Hello, that does not work for me...it pops up an error and says ws= wb[0] expects a string.

Comment: Hey @Kevin, that's not true.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use the `worksheets` property of the workbook object

```
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

Answer (score -6):

you need to use worksheet function sheet_by_name

```
sheet =  wb.sheet_by_name("Details")
```